# run spring boot non web project in eclipse and could specify file to read

Tags: eclipse

spring boot project and as a shell project, that is will execute like this, e.g. `querysq.jar < foo.txt`.

I found every time I modified code, I have to execute `mvn clean package -DskipTests` first, then execute `./target/querysq.jar < ~/foo.txt` to check the effect.

Could I just run this application in eclipse and still could specify which file to read just like in command line `< ~/foo.txt`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`<`, `>` and `>>` and shortcuts of your shell to redirect input or output from files or streams like changing from `SDTIN` to a file. I'm pretty sure that Eclipse does not spawn a shell before executing the command but directly starting the process you give. Therefore it will not work what you are trying above. But what you could do is to simple implement the behavior on your own by calling something like this as the first command in your `main` method:

```
if (args.length == 1 && !args[0].isEmpty() && args[0].startsWith("<")) {
   System.setIn(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(args[0].subString(1)), StandardOpenOption.READ));
}
```

I didn't tried out the above code but it should work or at least help you to go into the right direction. Obviously `Files.newInputStream()`, `Paths.get()` and `System.setIn()` could throw Exceptions which you should handle.

Comment: yeah, thanks! but actually your mean is solved this problem by explicitly specify filename in command line e.g. `querysq.jar -filename /home/foo/bar.txt`. however I want to use it as a shell script and I think this  method is a little cumbersome